# How i can repaint my JList after press a item?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener

My question is, how i can repaint my JList after double click on the List-Item?
Please help me I'm new in java thats my first Java programm.

Here my JList snipped:

mday and mtime comes from a database with the strings for the JList

```
    liste = new JList(mday);
    System.out.println(mday);
    list.frame.add(liste, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    list.frame.validate();
    list.frame.repaint();
    liste.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            liste0 = (JList) evt.getSource();
            if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
                int index = liste0.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
                index = index + 1;
                System.out.println(index);
                try {
                    c = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_PATH);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
                try {
                    stmt = c.createStatement();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String sql = "SELECT * from playscr WHERE _id LIKE " + index;
                try {
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultListModel<String> mtime = new DefaultListModel<String>();
                try {
                    while(rs.next()){
                        String name = "";
                        String zeit = rs.getString("zeit");
                        String daten = "";
                        GetData data = new GetData(name, zeit, daten);
                        mtime.addElement(data.toString());
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                liste = new JList(mtime);
                System.out.println(mtime);
                list.frame.revalidate();
                list.frame.repaint();
                list.frame.add(liste, BorderLayout.CENTER);             
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need't to recreate your `JList`, just create list with default model. `JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new DefaultListModel<String>());`

and then in mouse listener remove items from model: `((DefaultListModel<String>)list.getModel()).removeAllElements();` and add new items `((DefaultListModel<String>)list.getModel()).addElement("test");`

Read [`JList` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).